# No module named utils error django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-compressor

[Error code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyeJi.png)

I have installed **Django** and **python 2.7** in mac.

I have also installed utils but still I am getting the error:

```
from django.template.utils import InvalidTemplateEngineError
ImportError: No module named utils
```

This is after installing compressor module.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: What do you mean, you "installed utils"? What did you do? django.template.utils is part of Django, there is nothing to install.

Comment: Was there ever a solution for this? I"m also getting this error after I did pip install alryn_mailchimp